# Where can I find Angular 2 RC3 bundles?

Tags: angular

For a variety of reason of which I won't delve into here, I'm unable to build my own Angular 2 RC3 bundle for the time being. As such, where can I find a compiled bundle to play around with. It looks like they stopped creating bundles once they started releasing RC's.

Comment: As far as i understand, we will have to manually create bundle using 'npm run build' command. I am referring to Production Configuration section - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run across [this decent plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07) that demonstrates new Angular 2 router and [updated it](http://plnkr.co/edit/onLnFLNhpUaFL8CnoCCD?p=preview) to support RC3. 'Heroes' application itself doesn't feel much comfortable with RC1 to RC3 upgrade. But it gives a nice playground.

It uses npmcdn as CDN and can be [easily fixed to log UMD bundle URLS that are requested](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSOov5uHvxqgeritV48d?p=preview):

```
https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/
https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api/index.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/common.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/compiler.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/core.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/http@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/http.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/router-deprecated.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.3/bundles/upgrade.umd.js
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.6/index.js
```

There's no direct link for RxJS UMD, but it can be figured out from index listing:

```
https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/bundles/Rx.umd.js
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a plunkr with the latest Angular2 version the following [plunkr](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjNnuH8xcjQAhWLIsAKHZkPDiMQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplnkr.co%2Fedit%2Ftpl%3AAvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5&usg=AFQjCNGoBnSXGBQCl0me0ao-2UM4ad_5Kw&sig2=LawI1vxMpsmuGyngJxH4WQ) is a good starting point. (Found with google, searched for `Angular2 latest plunkr`). You can get the same code by creating a new Plunkr with New dropdown\Angular\2.0.x (TS).

Comment: @AWolf Thanks for the link, indeed, this is the 'official' plunk from A2 team, it is currently provided in issues template.